# YQ tool unable to substitute values

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a bash script that uses yq tool, which works pretty much, but is unable to substitute value.

The script basically loops through a bunch of yaml files and extracts values successfully, but unable to modify the file with actual values which were extracted earlier

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the path to the folder containing your YAML files
folder_path="./secrets"

# Loop through each YAML file in the folder
for yaml_file in "$folder_path"/*.yaml; do
  if [ -f "$yaml_file" ]; then
    # Extract the metadata.name field using yq
    name=$(yq eval '.metadata.name' "$yaml_file")
    namespace=$(yq eval '.metadata.namespace' "$yaml_file")

    yq eval '.metadata.labels."app.kubernetes.io/managed-by" = "Helm"' -i $yaml_file
    yq eval '.metadata.annotations."meta.helm.sh/release-name" = $name | .metadata.annotations."meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" = $namespace' -i $yaml_file
  fi
done
```

the output on running this script is

```
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: null
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: null
```

To be able to pull extracted values in the recipient file

Answer (score 0):

well well ,
it got sorted with this

```
yq eval '.metadata.annotations."meta.helm.sh/release-name" = "'${name}'" | .metadata.annotations."meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" =  "'${namespace}'"' -i $yaml_file
```